# Why do I have to put @ in front of `Name` in an object initializer?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

Purely curiosity at this point since the `@` fixed the problem I was having, but why is `Name` special?

I have an EF entity property called `Name`…if I don't put the `@` in front of `Name`, I don't get any kind of error, but the `Name` property on the object doesn't get assigned. If I put `@Name` in the object initializer, it assigns `Name` properly:

```
a = new Author
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    @Name = "Jason Hater" // Apparently "Name" is quasi-reserved or something...?!?
};
```

I checked the generated code, and it's just named `Name`:

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public global::System.String Name
{
    get
    {
        return _Name;
    }

    //...
}
```

So, `Name` isn't listed as a [keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx), so why is it special?

## Edit

Okay, as @sergey suggested, it's definitely a little more complicated than I first thought. Something goofy about Entity Framework specifically.

This is manifesting inside a unit testing class, that may be relevant also. I'm unsure what's relevant and what's not now unfortunately, so here's the whole `[TestInitialize]` method, and at the bottom of it you can see that the weirdness happens around `context.SaveChanges()`:

```
[TestClass]
public class EntityConverterTests
{
    private Author a;
    private Post p, p2, p3;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupEntities()
    {
        TestEntities context = new TestEntities();

        // Clear it out!
        foreach (Comment o in context.Comments) context.Comments.DeleteObject(o);
        foreach (Post o in context.Posts) context.Posts.DeleteObject(o);
        foreach (Author o in context.Authors) context.Authors.DeleteObject(o);
        context.SaveChanges();

        a = new Author
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Name = "Jason Hater"
        };
        context.Authors.AddObject(a);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a.Name); // "Jason Hater"…Yay!

        // probably irrelevant from here until context.SaveChanges()…?

        p = new Post()
        {
            Title = "Linkbait!",
            Author = a
        };
        p2 = new Post
        {
            Title = "Rant #1023",
            Author = a
        };
        p3 = new Post
        {
            Title = "Polemic in E-flat minor #824",
            Author = a
        };

        a.Posts.Add(p);
        a.Posts.Add(p2);
        a.Posts.Add(p3);

        p.Comments.Add(
            new Comment()
            {
                Body = "Nuh uh!",
                Post = p
            }
        );
        p.Comments.Add(
            new Comment()
            {
                Body = "Yeah huh!",
                Post = p
            }
        );
        p.Comments.Add(
            new Comment()
            {
                Body = "Third Reich.",
                Post = p
            }
        );

        p2.Comments.Add(
            new Comment
            {
                Body = "I laughed, I cried!",
                Post = p2
            }
        );

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a.Name); // "Jason Hater"…great!

        context.SaveChanges();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a.Name); // a.Name is null -> empty string!
    }

    // …

}
```

More coming, because now the `@` *isn't* "fixing" it--that is now I'm still seeing null in the test method I was seeing it correct before…something in another `[TestMethod]` may have been making a difference, perhaps…unsure, still investigating. Still, why is the change around `context.SaveChanges()` occurring?

## Edit 2

Uh, okay…somehow the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property on my `Name` property was set to "Identity" in the modeling GUI. No idea how that happened. Changing it to "None" may have eliminated my problem. But…I know I hadn't changed that back when I thought the `@` symbol had fixed it…something still odd here.

## Edit 3

One way or the other, the bad value for `StoreGeneratedPattern` was the cause of my assignment/saving problem. I'm unsure why I observed success one or more times with that setting, but the original question is no longer the correct question.

Comment: It's completely OK to use property `Name`. I believe your problem was elsewhere. Think about what else you have changed

Comment: _"the Name property on the object doesn't get assigned"_ - please create a small example that reproduces this issue.

Comment: A compiler error would also help

Comment: @JoshSmeaton As I stated, I got no error. The assignment just didn't take. I'm working to provide an example, but as Sergey suggested, I may have a more complex situation than I originally thought. Stand by...

Comment: @S'pht'Kr sorry I didn't read the question thoroughly enough.

Comment: @S'pht'Kr, C# is case sensitive and all keywords are all lower case. Either way, if it was a C# thing, it would either compile or not. `@` couldn't have fixed or unfixed anything. Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the setter of the `Name` property to see what's happening?

Comment: I have made plenty of models with a `string Name` property with no problems. So you can rule that out as the problem - it's something more elusive.

Answer (score 2):

In C# the `@` is used if you want turn a keyword into an identifier. Since `Name` is no keyword, it has no effect at all.

This is purely a C# rule, at the IL level the `@` won't be present anymore, even if the name of the identifier matches a C# keyword. So it is impossible for Entity Framework to detect the difference.

Comment: Why does C# allow you to put `@` on identifiers that aren't keywords? I'm wondering if it's so you can compile new code on older compilers that didn't have the newer keyword(s)

Comment: @NickStrupat Yes, that's precisely the reason. Funnily enough, the C# team almost never introduces new keywords. The new keyword look things are usually either contextual (so they can't appear in a context where they could be identifiers) or they're not keywords at all (`var` isn't a keyword, it can actually refer to a type called `var` if there is one)

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. I knew about the LINQ expression contextual keywords but I assumed `var` was a keyword. How do you use `var` when you have a type called `var` in the namespace? Same case with `dynamic` it seems.

Answer (score 0):

"Why do I have to put @ in front of `Name` in an object initializer?"  - You don't, your problem is elsewhere as commenters have already suggested.

When performing a `DbContext.SaveChanges` the way that objects in the object graph get changed   is when there is a `StoreGeneratedPattern` associated with a given property mapping.

Check to see if a `StoreGeneratedPattern` is associated with your `Author.Name` mapping.

Comment: Hey that's cheating, I already put that in one of my edits :-). But, I'll give it to you if you can tell me why, with a `StoreGeneratedPattern` set to `Identity`, that this might have _worked_ exactly _once_ and _not_ the first time? That's what's driving me crazy now. I swear I didn't change that and it must have been set that way since the model was built, but it worked once--when I put the `@` on there (even though as everyone agrees that wasn't what fixed it).